# Brew becomes unusable when a new terminal window opens

Tags: command-line, package-management

I installed brew and the installation was successful.  I was able to run `brew doctor` and get the output.  I opened a new window and `Command 'brew' not found...`

but when I run `eval "$(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)"` brew works.

I think this means I need to add brew to my PATH, but I have `export PATH="$PATH:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew"` in my .bashrc file, so what else can I do?

Comment: Add the eval command to your .bashrc -- there are more env vars than just PATH that are set with that "shellenv" command.

Comment: @glennjackman you are right, thank you